# How to send emails with GPG signing through Pantheon-mail

Tags: pantheon-mail, gpg

The title explains it all how does one set up `pantheon-mail` to send emails signed with `gpg`.

Is it possible through the UI or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no PGP/GPG support for now, but a feature request already has been filed, you can mark that it affects you as well: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-mail/+bug/1517988

You might want to post a bounty as well:  https://www.bountysource.com/issues/1353854-transparent-encryption-and-signing-with-gpg